# set Cursor to desired point c#

Tags: c#, winapi, cursor

Im trying to move my cursor according to my hand point in kinect, I can get the real coordinates I mean I can move an image on screen but I want real cursor to be settled according to my hand coordinates. I tried Console.SetCursor(x,y) but it gives exception I also tried to download windows forms dll but I cant find the version 4.00 . Is there any simple way to set cursor in a desired position? (which is working by the way and as  I said Console.SetcursorPosition is not wodking?)

Comment: Is this a console application? If not, what kind of app is it?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
Cursor.Position = new Point();
```

You can find more information's [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx&ei=Kk0ET4jnGKWB4gSo3ZmFDw&usg=AFQjCNHAvJMTtv1ehzI8I9ShOrA6ITIrwg&sig2=Mtro9JpyHeiTKQ1QId5eXQ)

Comment: It gives compilation error I could not understand why but thanx by the way
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y); works. :)

Comment: Well it must be something else because this will work for sure ,just set Point objec X and Y values and try not to move the cursor out the Screen it might throw that exception.

Comment: Cursor.Position "Does not contain a definition for Position ..."error

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide very much information about you app but I suspect that you just need to assign to [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) from `System.Windows.Forms`. You may need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in order to gain access to this, depending on exactly what type of project you have.

If you want to keep it lightweight and avoid taking a reference to WinForms then you could just [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetCursorPos.html) to [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I have  one more question ? What should I extern to make double click, click, to use wheel functions?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for question and answer.

I found strange and unobvious behavior.

Let you use multi-monitor (two or three monitor) configuration, and use two windows in your application.

One window is active, and you set cursor position for second windows.

And this two windows located on **different** monitors.

Then, you need call SetCursorPos TWICE!

TWICE, who would have thought?

Firs call move cursor to virtual borderline between monitors.

And only second call move cursor to required position second window!

Example of code (after 6 hours of experiments):

```
            SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle); // set second window active
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x20, this.Handle, (IntPtr)1); // Send WM_SETCURSOR

            SetCursorPos(400, 600);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            SetCursorPos(400, 600);
```